# Display comments on a comment page without form

Tags: categories, comments, comment-form

I'm using this to allow me to display my comments for posts on category pages:

```
<?php
$wp_query->is_single = true;
comments_template();
$wp_query->is_single = false;
?>
```

However I don't want to display the comment form.  Is there a way to display the comments only on a comment page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) and pass the post ID as parameter. Then print the result as regular list. From a [plugin](https://gist.github.com/4503390) I have published recently:

```
function t5_list_comments( $atts, $content = '' )
{
    '' !== $content && $content = wpautop( do_shortcode( $content ) );

    if ( ! isset ( $atts['post_id'] ) )
        return 'Please pass an argument for "post_id"';

    if ( ! $comments = get_comments( $atts ) )
        return 'No comments found for post ID '. esc_html( $atts['post_id'] );

    $out = $content . '<ul class="t5-comment-list">';
    foreach ( $comments as $comment )
    {
        $out .= sprintf(
            '<li>%1$s - %2$s %3$s</li>',
            get_comment_author_link( $comment->comment_ID ),
            get_comment_date( 'd.m.Y H:i', $comment->comment_ID ),
            wpautop( $comment->comment_content )
        );
    }

    return $out . '</ul>';
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
print t5_list_comments( array ( 'post_id' => get_the_ID() ) );
```

Comment: this works great, just can't figure out how to format the comment date using `wpautop( $comment->comment_date)`.  Any idea?

Comment: @JonnyPlow See my update.